# Bernstein's Theorem (Probability)

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I am doing an exercise that establishes the Bernstein's Theorem (it's called that way in french i don't know if it is known with this name in english). It states the following :

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) $ be a probability space. We suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables with same law of probability. Let $U=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$.
> Then $U$ is independant of $V$ iff $X$ and $Y$ are two variables of normal distribution.

The goal of the exercise is to show this with a supplementary assumption that is $E(X^2)=E(Y^2)< \infty$.

I have done the first two parts of the exercise with is establishing the $ \implies$ way and we have shown that the following relation characterize the characteristic function  of the standard normal distribution,
\begin{align}
\phi^2=\phi '^2-\phi \phi ''
\end{align}

Where $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \phi(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX})$ is the characteristic function of X.

For the direct implication of the theorem i am stuck, the exercise suppose that $\mathbb{E}(X)=0, Var(X)=1$, $X$ independant of $Y$ and they are of same probability law.

What i have shown :

$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \phi_U(t)=\phi_{X+Y}(t)=\phi_X(t)^2   $ and $ \phi_V(t)=\phi_X(t)\phi_X(-t)$ using independance and the fact that $X$ and $Y$ have same law.
Then i showed that, :

$\forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}, \phi_{(U,V)}(u,v)=\phi_U(u) \phi_V(v)=\phi_X(u)^2\phi_X(v)\phi_X(-v) $ because $U$ and $V$ are supposed independant.

And this is where i'm stuck because the next question is

> Which relation $\phi_{U,V}$ has to satisfie for $U$ and $V$ to be independant

But i feel like the relation is the one i used to write $\phi_{(U,V)}(u,v)=\phi_U(u) \phi_V(v)$.

The next question is

> Deduce that for all $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have $\phi_X(u+v)\phi_X(u-v)=\phi_X(u)^2\phi_X(v) \phi_X(-v)$.

Then we use this relation to get the one that characterize the characteristic function  of the standard normal distribution and then i would be easy to conclude.

What am i not understanding properly ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your equation
$$
 \phi_{(U,V)}(u,v)=\phi_U(u) \phi_V(v)=\phi_X(u)^2\phi_X(v)\phi_X(-v)
$$
is correct. Therefore, in order to answer the next question, you need to prove
$$
\phi_{(U,V)}(u,v)\stackrel{?}=\phi_X(u+v)\phi_X(u-v)
$$
To prove this, write
$$
\phi_{(U,V)}(u,v)=\mathbb E\left[e^{i(uU+vV)}\right],\tag{$*$}
$$
substitute $U=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$ into $(*)$, then rearrange.

Comment: \begin{align}
\phi_{(U,V)} (u,v)&= \mathbb{E} (e^{i(uU+Vv)}) \\
&=\mathbb{E} ( e^{i(u(X+Y)+v(X-Y))} \\
&=\mathbb{E} ( e^{i(uX+uY)+vX-vY))} \\
&=\mathbb{E} ( e^{i(X(u+v)+Y(u-v))} \\
&=\mathbb{E} ( e^{i(X(u+v))} \mathbb{E} ( e^{i(Y(u-v))}) \textbf{ by independance of $X$ and $Y$}\\
&=\phi_X(u+v) \phi_Y (u-v)  \\
&=\phi_X(u+v) \phi_X (u-v) \textbf{ because $X$ and $Y $ have same law}\\
\end{align}

But i don't quite see where the independance of $U$ and $V$ is used.
I find the question weird.

Comment: You used the independence of $U$ and $V$ in your equation $\phi_{(U,V)}(u,v)=\phi_U(u) \phi_V(v)=\phi_X(u)^2\phi_X(v)\phi_X(-v)$, right? You should have all the pieces now.

Comment: Oh, so the relation that $\phi_X$ has to satisfy is $\phi_X(t)\phi_X(-t)=\phi_X(u)^2\phi_X(v)\phi_X(-v)$ if it is verified then $U$ and $V$ are independant ? But i feel like the exercise has the questions in the wrong order though.
If i understand right then $\phi_{(U,V)}(u,v)=\phi_U(u) \phi_V(v)=\phi_X(u)^2\phi_X(v)\phi_X(-v)$ is the answer to the question ? And the other relation that we found is true because $X$ and $Y$ are independant.

Comment: @vadkoslo The important thing is that you have a correct proof that you understand every step of.